# how do i use parent.frames [] to refer one webpage to another?

Tags: javascript, function, parent-child

i believe that i have to use an array but im not sure where it should be placed and how it should look. im working with javascript and am kinda new at it.  should the array be in the   tags? or the  tag? or should it be inside of the  tags but outside of the other two? im lost. should the array be written in just the parent file or the child file? or both? i have created two different pages and now i want the button on one page to return the other page and the button on the child page to close the window. which i think involves the close() option since i used the open() to bring up a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean. The way one window accesses another window's properties depends on how they relate; from "child" frame to parent, from parent to "child", from "child" to "sibling"...

If you want to access another frame from within a frame, you're probably best off giving the other frame an id and using something like `parent.getElementById("yourId").contentWindow`. This will give you the other frame's window object, on which you can call `close()`.

I think [this link](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/index.html?page=7) explains how to access windows, frames and parents.

Comment: how would i assignt an id to each web page? is it the same as with an array? i.e  parent.frame [0] (for the parent) and parent.frame [1] for the child?

Comment: You'd have to assign an id attribute to the `element` containing the frame (i. e. the iframe). `parent.frames` is an array of all the frames of the parent.

Comment: okay so then i would place the parent.frames in the first page and it should refrence the second page when i click on the button to pull up a new window right?

Comment: so would the array look like this: var aboutDialog = new array (2);

aboutDialog [0]
aboutHtml [1]

parent.frame(aboutDialog[0]);
parent.frame(aboutHtml [1]);

Comment: thanks alot! i finally got it working! (1:18 am but hey im committed lol! )